# ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined using Puppeteer's page.pdf() on AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, chromium

I have implemented a PDF download feature in my current project using Puppeteer. I'm hosting the project on AWS with Node 18.

Locally, it works perfectly fine, but in production when I hit the PDF download API, it returns the following error:  `ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined`.

Puppeteer version is 22.3.0

Here is the Puppeteer code:

```js
public getReportPdf = async(req: Request, res: Response) = >{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    const {
      reportId
    } = req.params;
    const reportData = await this.reportRepo.getJobAndTemplateWithReport(reportId);
    const htmlData = await ejs.renderFile('src/helper/templates/report.ejs', {
      record: reportData[0],
      reportOverview: REPORT_OVERVIEW
    });
    const image = await getBase64Image('https://maxscaffold-front-stg.taskgrids.com/assets/images/Max-Builders-Default.png') // Need to pass here companyLogo url
    await page.setContent(htmlData);
    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
      displayHeaderFooter: true,
      headerTemplate: ` < div style = "font-size: 10px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin-left: 300px" > <div > Powered by < /div>
        <img style="height: 50px; width: auto; margin-left: 5px" src="data:image/png;
      base64,
      $ {
        image
      }
      "/>
        </div>`,
        format: 'A4',
        printBackground: true,
        preferCSSPageSize: true,
        scale: 0.8,
        margin: {
          top: '100px',
          bottom:'50px'
        }
      });
      await page.close();
      await browser.close();

      const savepath = `./${STORAGE_BUCKET.DEFAULT}/${reportId}_report.pdf`;

      fs.writeFile(savepath, pdfBuffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('err', err);
        }
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        fs.promises.unlink(savepath);
      }, 25000);

  
      const data = process.env.NODE_URL + `api/images/${reportId}_report.pdf`;
       return generalResponse(req, res,data, successMessage.REPORT_DISPLAY_SUCCESS, true, responseFlag.SUCCESS);
    } catch (error) {
      await page.close();
      await browser.close();
      return generalResponse(req, res, error, errorMessage.SOMETHING_WRONG, false, responseFlag.ERROR);
    }
  };"
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

I have tried Node version 18 locally, then it works perfectly, but I don't know why in production it gives an error.

[This is error message which I get from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nQSp.png)

Error message (I'm not sure which line is causing the error):

```
error:  ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined
at getReadableFromProtocolStream (/var/www/max-scaffolds/backend/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:241:5)
at CdpPage.createPDFStream (/var/www/max-scaffolds/backend/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Page.js:845:66)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async CdpPage.pdf (/var/www/max-scaffolds/backend/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Page.js:849:26)
```

Comment: Can you copy the full, exact error message stack trace? Thanks. This looks like a repost of [Node js puppeteer Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78168080/node-js-puppeteer-implementation) which wasn't clear enough to answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with error image

Comment: Thanks, but please provide it as text, so it can be searched: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Is the line that's throwing `await page.pdf(...)`?

Comment: I have added error message in form of text as well as in image

Comment: I am not sure which line causing the error

Comment: Thanks, this should be sufficient for someone to answer (I'm not an AWS person, just Puppeteer, so I probably can't reproduce it). That said, you can determine the line by logging on each line and seeing how far you get. [Minimizing the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to isolate the problem makes it easier to solve.

Comment: I want to know that is it possible to add headless mode so the error will resolved ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check 3 main paramter in **Local** and **Live**

- Puppeteer version
- Node version
- Chromium version

Above three parameter should match than and only than above issue is resolve
In my case i have done

- Puppeteer version :- 22.4.1
- Node version :- 22.11.0
- Chromium version :- set according to your live and local